# How can I update record in file in c++?

Tags: c++

In below mentioned code of function. I am not able to update balance(deposits and withdrawals) in file my.dat. Please advise where am I doing it wrong. (I am a newbie).

```
 void dep_with(int e, int f)
 {
 int amt;
 int recordFind=0;
 account ac;
 ifstream updatedata("E:\\c++ Project\\final thoughts\\my.dat", ios::in|ios::out);
 while(updatedata.read((char*) &ac, sizeof(ac)) && recordFind==0)
 {
          if(ac.get_account()==e)
          {
                  ac.view_account();
                  if(f==1)
                  {
                          cout<<"\nEnter the amount to be deposited";
                          cin>>amt;
                          ac.deposits(amt);        
                  }
                  if(f==2)
                  {
                          cout<<"\nEnter the amount to be withdraw";
                          cin>>amt;
                          ac.withdrawls(amt);
                  }
                  int pos=(-1)*sizeof(ac);
                  ofstream updatedata("E:\\c++ Project\\final thoughts\\my.dat",    ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
                  updatedata.seekp(pos,ios::cur);
                  updatedata.write((char*) &ac, sizeof(ac));
                  cout<<"\n\n\tRecord Updated";
                  recordFind=1;                      
          }                        

 }
 updatedata.close();
 if(recordFind==0)
 {
                  cout<<"\n\nRecord not Found";                 
 }
 }
```

Comment: You should provide minimal sample code. You did not provide structure defination.

Comment: Instead of opening a second file for writing (which might not be possible on all platforms), why not open the first file reading *and* writing, and then use that to write as well as read.

Comment: _'I am not able to update'_ is a pretty poor problem/error description.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I missed the fact that he actually uses two stream objects.  That can't be made to work; on some systems, the fact that a file is open anywhere means that you cannot open it for writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.  First, `updatedata` is a
`std::ifstream`, which means that it doesn't have functions like `write`
or `seekp`.  Second, you've opened it in text mode, so you cannot seek
to an arbitrary position in the file; you can only seek to the beginning
or the end, or to a position which was returned by `tellg` or `tellp`.
(It's undefined behavior otherwise.) You'll have to memorize the
position before each `read`, and work from that.)  Third, you don't show
the definition of `account`, but in general, you cannot use 
`istream::read` and `ostream::write` directly on objects of the type:
you have to format the output and parse the input, using an intermediate
buffer.

EDIT:

I've just noticed that you actually open the file a second time for
writing.  This cannot be made to work for several reasons, not the least
of which is that some systems will not allow opening a file with write
access if the file is already open elsewhere.  Other than that: you open
with `std::ios_base::app`, which means that all writes will append to
the end of the file, regardless of where the position marker was before.

In summary:

- You need to use an `std::fstream`.
- You need to memorize the position (using `tellg`) *before* each read,
  and seek back to it if you want to write.
- You need to use an intermediate buffer for the data.  (This may not
  be necessary *if* 1) the program which reads and writes the data is
  compiled with the same compiler, using the same options, on the same
  machine, running under the same OS, and 2) the data structure is a pure
  POD.  These conditions are almost never met in well written C++.)